# Why Can I Not Access My Devices Localhost Over Data?

Tags: web-server

While experimenting with the Bit Web Server app I have noticed that when I attempt to access my device's localhost, the connection seems to be sent somewhere else.

Using the localhost button in the app sends me to `http://localhost:8080`, however this displays a blank page, whilst removing the port number takes me to a page that has the following written on it:  `Bytemobile Dummy Web Server`.

When accessing `http://localhost:8080` with no connection (WiFi and Data are turned off) I simply get `Unable to connect to the proxy server`.
I can however connect to my device's localhost fine when connected to WiFi.

Why can I not connect to my device's localhost? Surely it should not need a connection for it to connect to itself. Why does it only work when WiFi is enabled and how do I change this behavior?

Comment: This is rather a networking question, and not specific to Android. If you ommit the `:8080`, this corresponds to using `:80`, which is the port a web server usually listens to. Most likely reason for your error is: there's nothing listening on port 8080.

Comment: Bit Web Server is listening to :8080 by default.I expected :8080 to display the webpage and :80 to not connect.

Since disabling the proxy in my APN setting everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the error message, which says it can't connect to the **proxy** server. If your device is configured to use a web proxy, then it'll never connect directly to localhost: it connects to the web proxy and asks that for the web page you really want. This won't work with a local web server.

To use a local web server, turn off your web proxy settings. See [this related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28726/cant-access-tethered-server-from-android-browser-time-out-or-url-blocked) for more info about that.

Comment: Thanks, turns out my problem was a little different.
It was a proxy but it was in my APN settings.